# How do I create this specific layout in TinyMCE 4 popup?

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce

Back in TinyMCE 3 it was really easy to edit/add the popups because it was all plain HTML. 
Now is totally different and I'm getting lost on which type of item is each.
I was able to gather all the possible types by debugging `tinymce.js` and `table plugin` because the documentation lacks of all this, there is no help at all on how to build layouts and its items.

This would be the list of possible items:

```
absolutelayout
button
buttongroup
checkbox
collection
colorbox
colorbutton
colorpicker
combobox
container
control
draghelper
elementpath
factory
fieldset
filepicker
fitlayout
flexlayout
floatpanel
flowlayout
form
formitem
gridlayout
iframe
keyboardnavigation
label
layout
listbox
menu
menubar
menubutton
menuitem
messagebox
movable
panel
panelbutton
path
radio
resizable
resizehandle
scrollable
selector
spacer
splitbutton
stacklayout
tabpanel
textbox
throbber
toolbar
tooltip
widget
window
```

Now, if I want to create a layout such like this:

`(Label -> Input text -> Button)` in a single row, how can I do that?

I need to modify the table's plugin to enable the possibility of adding a background image browsing, we already have a file manager, so when I do click on Browse button, i search the image and insert it in the table.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The TinyMCE API docs are garbage. Where did you even find this list you provided? Thanks!

Comment: @ColinMarshall I wouldn't even call them "docs". It is easier to read minified JS source than that maze of links to nothingness.

Comment: haha yes @ColinMarshall, i found it digging in the tinymce.js file :) otherwise it's impossible to get that list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself, it was kinda easy to do. I post just in case someone else needs it.

```
{
                        layout: 'flow',
                        name: 'align',
                        type: 'form',
                        direction: 'column',
                        items: [
                                {
                                    label: 'Background image',
                                    type: 'textbox',
                                    name: 'bgimage'                                 
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'button',
                                    name: 'bgimage',
                                    icon: 'browse',                                 
                                }
                            ]

                    },
```